# How to query with a list of id in Bookshelf JS

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

How can I get a list of records by PK in a single query using [bookshelf.js](/questions/tagged/bookshelf.js)?

The end query should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN (1,3,5,6,7);
```

Comment: did you try something like `model.where('ID', [1,3,5,7,8]).fetch().then(function() {  });`

Comment: Yep, but syntax error :)

Answer (score 14):

This solution works:

```
AdModel
  .where('search_id', 'IN', [1, 2, 3])
  .fetchAll();
```

You can also use the Knex QueryBuilder to get the same result

```
AdModel
.query(qb => {
    qb.whereIn('search_id',  [1, 2, 3]);
})
.fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks DeadEye, I found the solution with Knex something like knex.select('name').from('users')
  .whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
  .orWhereIn('id', [4, 5, 6])

Comment: Right, with knex.js, this is way much simple (;

Comment: Note that the order of the results is not guaranteed to be the same as the query. This is important if you are abstracting a batch loader, such as in the case of https://github.com/facebook/dataloader.

Comment: @VũNguyễn but how can I do a `whereIn` with `withRelated`?

Comment: @Growler I you use knex, you'll be able to use whereIn, bu as far as I know, you won't be able to do this in Bookshelf. Execute a query to get your `WHERE IN` list and then use `AdModel.where('search_id', 'IN', result.toJSON())`

Comment: Updated the answer with a way much better answer for querying Bookshelf using Knex QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

List (single) query and fetching relations (withRelated)

```
BookshelfModel
  .where('field_id', 'IN', [1, 2, 3])
  .fetchAll({withRelated: ["tableA", "tableB"]});
```